# In data explorer why the first character of the month name is in lowercase for created and edited fields

Tags: support, data-explorer, date-format

Why the month name's first character is showing as lower case for the `created`, `edited` in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) site.

In other SE sites the first character for the month name is in Caps, is there any reason they are following like this only for SEDE?

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Month name first character is lowercase]

Comment: I'd say minor overlook, or just different style of writing. Keep in mind that SEDE is open source, with developers who are not SE developers